# Gradle Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud-foundry, gradlew

i use gradle-wrapper and have Gradle 6.8 installed.

Succesfull Runs:
bash gradlew check
bash gradlew test

Failed Runs:
`

```
Task :findMainClass FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':findMainClass' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':findMainClass' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
:findMainClass (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':findMainClass'.
'java.io.File org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()'
```

`

This is my build.gradle:
`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

ext {
    bootVersion = "1.5.2.RELEASE"
}

//apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    //mavenLocal()

    //maven { url "http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot" }
    //maven { url "http://repo.springsource.org/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-core', version: '1.2.9.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-spring-service-connector', version: '1.2.9.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector', version: '1.2.9.RELEASE'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:${bootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${bootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${bootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${bootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${bootVersion}"
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.113'
    runtimeOnly "org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.18"
    runtimeOnly "mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6"
    implementation group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.3'
}


task wrapper1(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '6.0.1'
}
```

`

and this is my gradle-wrapper.properties:
`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists distributionUrl=file:///tmp/my-project/gradle-6.8-all.zip zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists`

Can you help me to solve this issue?

I was trying to deploy an cloudfoundry test applciation: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/cf-s3-demo